# What is the etymology of "dewclaw"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

A *dewclaw* is a vestigial digit on the foot of some mammals, notably dogs.

Here's a picture of a dog's paw with an arrow pointing to the *dewclaw*.

[image: dewclaw]

The *claw* part is obvious enough, but why *dew*?

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid that no one knows for sure.  The word is some four hundred years old. Dictionary.com maintains that it may be related to the kind of dew that appears overnight, but it cannot fortify the claim.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dew) says:

> also *dew-claw*, 1570s, from ***claw***, but the signification of the first element is obscure (see ***dewlap***).

*Dewlap* is further down in the same entry:

> mid-14c., *dewe lappe*, from *lappe* "loose piece" (O.E. *læppa*), first element of unknown origin or meaning. Originally of cattle.

Dictionary.com is virtually identical on *dewclaw* (it refers to *dewlap* too), but there is a little more in its origin entry on *dewlap*:

> 1350–1400; Middle English *dew(e)lappe*, apparently *dewe* [dew](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dew) + *lappe* lap1; compare Danish *dog-læp*, Dutch (dial.) *dauw-zwengel*; literal sense is unclear

[YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/dewclaw) cites American Heritage Dictionary, 4th Ed. for a claim that "dew" may be an alteration of "toe", but it also says *prob. so called because it does not touch the ground, but only the dew on the surface*.

*Dog* or *dew* may be cognate with Scots *dewg*/Old Scots *duig*, always used in the plural and having the meaning "small pieces, shreds, fragments" (see [Dictionary of the Scots Language](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/)), suggesting "fragmentary claw". This connection was proposed in a thread on the subject at [The Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=332068).

Comment: The possible connection with Scots is interesting as, given the evidence here, it doesn't seem related to the water *dew*.

Answer (score 2):

The OED says

> Apparently < dew n. + claw n. (Perhaps referring to the fact that
>   while the other claws come in contact with the soil, or press the
>   grass to the ground, this only brushes the dewy surface.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone long ago waxed poetic and, while watching his hounds on an early morning hunt, thought the dewclaw 'claws' the dew.  Or am I waxing silly?

Comment: All I can add is that humor has been at the center of many other phrases and words. I don't think dewclaw has a sound explanation anywhere, so maybe a little less serious than trying to relate it to old words as with the Scottish reference.